# Swapping who you're family sharing with

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

I'm family sharing with two different people, they both own Binding of Isaac, and I do not. I want to play Binding of Isaac, but one of the two people is playing the game already. Is there anyway to borrow the game from the other person's account?